# Proper way to concatenate a tuple with keys and values

Tags: python, tuples

I have a tuple that is populated with elements from a directory:

```
{'C:/foo' : ['bar1', 'bar2'], 'C:/foo2' : ['bar']}
```

and I am trying to concatenate each key with its values:

```
C:/foo/bar1
C:/foo/bar2
C:/foo2/bar
```

I thought this would work:

```
[''.join('%s/%s' % (d.keys(), value)) for value in d.values()]
```

But it's just concatenating the key with the value in the same way as:

```
for k,v in d.items():
  print(k'/'v)
```

Any help in this area would be greatly appreciated! If I am going at this the wrong way please tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looping over the values, you need to loop over the keys, then loop over the values for that key.

Comment: Your research would be easier if you knew that was a dictionary of string keys and list values, not a tuple.

Comment: For this example, yes it's a Dictionary. I'm using os.walk and that returns a tuple.

Comment: @i73: are you confusing the `(root, files, dirs)` tuple with the *lists* used for `files` and `dirs` perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `os.path.join` to build up paths in this manner.

```
import os
d = {'C:/foo' : ['bar1', 'bar2'], 'C:/foo2': ['bar']}
for k,v in d.items():
    for value in v:
        print(os.path.join(k,value))
```

Output

```
C:/foo2\bar
C:/foo\bar1
C:/foo\bar2
```

Then to make sure the slashes are all the correct way you can use `os.path.normpath`

```
for k,v in d.items():
    for value in v:
        print(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(k,value)))
```

Output

```
C:\foo2\bar
C:\foo\bar1
C:\foo\bar2
```

To be clear, you should prefer using [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/os.path.html) because it will robustly handle path manipulation in an operating system specific manner. In this case ensuring the correct number of slashes (including escaping if necessary), and which types of slashes (forward vs backward).

Answer (score 1):

You first need to iterate through the dictionary, and then iterate through the lists.

You can do this in a simple list comprehension, without using a for loop.

```
files_dict = {'C:/foo' : ['bar1', 'bar2'], 'C:/foo2' : ['bar']}
filenames = [dir+"/"+file for dir, files in files_dict.items() for file in files]
```

Output:

```
['C:/foo/bar1', 'C:/foo/bar2', 'C:/foo2/bar']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your tuples list, a colon is missing:

```
a = {'C:/foo' : ['bar1', 'bar2'], 'C:/foo2': ['bar']}

for key in a.keys():
    vals = a[key]
    for v in vals:
        concat = key + '/' + v
        print concat
```

Comment: Ah yes, thanks. I was just showing an example, I am not using this in my actual code :)